# Netplan - How to describe veth peer links?

Tags: networking, netplan

I want to peer connect between two bridges in my netplan configuration.

Under `iproute2` the commands would be:

```
ip link add dev vethb1 type veth peer name vethb2       
brctl addif br1 vethb1
brctl addif br2 vethb2
```

I'm porting from OpenVSwitch, so it's possible I'm thinking about this the wrong way.

Unfortunately, [the netplan documentation](https://netplan.io/reference) doesn't seem to cover all device types, particularly `veth`. Although it does mention `veth` in terms of matching, so there's some part of netplan that must know what it means.

I've tried doing a `vlan` with no `id` but it expects an id.

Creating an `ethernet` doesn't seem to accept a `type` or `peer` attribute.  [Networkd calls this `kind`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd) but that isn't an accepted key either.

**What does a `veth peer` link look like in a netplan config?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@slangasek is correct.  As of 0.39 there is no support in the netplan yaml.  However, `netplan` is based on `systemd-networkd` and plays nicely with it.  So here's the solution I came up with:

Create a file called `/etc/systemd/network/25-veth-b1b2.netdev` with the contents:

```
[NetDev]
Name=vethb1
Kind=veth
[Peer]
Name=vethb2
```

Then add to your `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

Under:

```
ethernets:
```

Add:

```
    vethb1: {}
    vethb2: {}
```

What this does is tells netplan to *expect* interfaces from somewhere called `vethb1` and `vethb2`.  (`{}` is an empty match.  `match: {}` works also, but leaving it blank or just `match:` causes a parsing error.)

Then you can add those interfaces to your bridge:

```
bridges:
  b1:
    interfaces: [vethb1]
  b2:
    interfaces: [vethb2]
```

Then rebuild your netplan config and restart systemd-networkd:

```
$ netplan generate
$ service systemd-networkd stop
$ service systemd-networkd start
```

Comment: Works great, cheers! Would like to mention that atleast for Netplan 0.99 on Ubuntu 20.04 you do not need to explicitly restart systemd-networkd, a regular `netplan apply` does the job. In case one wants to change the MTU of the VETH pair that should also be done in the Netplan config, but I had to remove any `match: {}` definitions otherwise I get the error "No valid settings found in the [Match] section, ignoring file" from systemd-networkd.

Answer (score 1):

As of netplan 0.39, there is no support for configuring veth devices through netplan yaml.  This is currently under consideration for implementation in a future release.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the functionality?  Perhaps by creating a networkd.netdev file?

Comment: Yes, veth is supported directly in systemd-networkd as described in systemd.netdev(5).